# How to get root folder path for UWP project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

To create a log file using NLog library we have to get root folder path for specific platform.

In iOS we can get it this way:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetRootFolder))]
namespace Sample.iOS.DependencyServices
{
    public class GetRootFolder : IGetRootFolder
    {
        string IGetRootFolder.GetRootFolder()
        {
            string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            return folder;
        }
    }
}
```

---

For Android we have this way:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetRootFolder))]

namespace Sample.Droid.DependencyServices
{
    public class GetRootFolder : IGetRootFolder
    {

        string IGetRootFolder.GetRootFolder()
        {
            var folder = $"{Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Log").CanonicalPath}";
            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }
            return folder;
        }
    }
}
```

#### How we can get folder path for UWP project in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: neither of those is the "root" path of your app, they are just writable paths available to the app.  You should be able to use `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum in the shared project, without having to use `DependencyService` to do this

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, you could use the code below to get the app's installation folder.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetPath))]
namespace App1.UWP
{
class GetPath : IGetPath
{
    public void Getpath()
    {
        // Get the app's installation folder.
        StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        // Print the folder's path to the Visual Studio Output window.
        Debug.WriteLine(appFolder.Name + " folder path: " + appFolder.Path);
    }
}
}
```